# react-native-audio-streaming and node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm building an app react native that use the component react-native-audio-streaming, but i'll love to have my repo music, so i'd like to connect node server for pipe my mp3 file over the net. Buuuut the problem is that if i call the server with browser, the streaming start, but if i make with the :
ReactNativeAudioStreaming.play("http://127.0.0.1:5000/get/5abad23b4f078f94aaf75400", {showIniOSMediaCenter: false, showInAndroidNotifications: false});
is not working.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

`{showIniOSMediaCenter: true, showInAndroidNotifications: true}`
If it is false then it does not work.